# Infinitesimal Generator of Poisson process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, poisson-distribution

I would like to compute the *infinitesimal generator* of a Poisson process $N$ with intensity $\lambda$.

So I can write:

$$\mathbb{E}[\ f(N_{t+s})-f(N_s)\ |\ \mathcal{F_t^0} \ ]  = \mathbb{E}[\ f(N_{t+s}-N_s+N_s)-f(N_s)\ |\ \mathcal{F_t^0} \ ]$$

$$= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-t \lambda}(\lambda t)^k}{k!}\cdot(\ f(N_{t}+k)-f(N_t)\ ) $$

where $\mathcal{F_t^0}$ is the raw filtration generated by $N$ and $f$ is a *bounded* and *measurable* function.

The result of the series should be:

$$\lambda t e^{-\lambda t}[\ f(N_{t}+1)-f(N_t)\ ] +O(t^2)$$

but I do not see how. I tried to manipulate the series as it is done for the computation of the expected value of a Poisson random variable but did not get anywhere.

Comment: Do you mean $O(t^2)$ (instead of $O(h^2)$)?

Comment: yes ! I will correct it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\lambda t} (\lambda t)^k}{k!} (f(N_t+k)-f(N_t)) = I_1+I_2+I_3$$

where

\begin{align*} I_1 &:= e^{-\lambda t} \cdot 1 \cdot (f(N_t+0)-f(N_t))=0, \\
I_2 &:= e^{-\lambda t} \lambda t (f(N_t+1)-f(N_t)) \end{align*}

and

$$I_3 := \sum_{k \geq 2} e^{-\lambda t} \frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!} (f(N_t+k)-f(N_t)).$$

It remains to show that $|I_3| \leq O(t^2)$. To this end, we note that

$$\begin{align*} |I_3| &\leq 2 \|f\|_{\infty} e^{-\lambda t}  \sum_{k \geq 2} \frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!} \\ &= 2 \|f\|_{\infty} e^{-\lambda t} (e^{\lambda t}-1-\lambda t) \\ &\leq 2 \lambda^2 \|f\|_{\infty} t^2. \end{align*}$$

(For the last step use e.g. Taylor's formula.)

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is very clear.
However, it shows me how to prove the result given previous information about it. How would you get it if you would not know the final answer?

Comment: @mastro What do you mean by "previous information"? How to show that the conditional expectation equals the given series?

Comment: I mean, if you did not know the final result, once you arrive at the series representation of the expected value, how would you proceed?

Comment: @maestro Well, exactly the same way. Since you are interested in the asymptotics (in $t$), it makes sense to split up the series in several parts, doesn't it?

Comment: In fact, I would be interested to know how you found $\mathbb E[f(N_{t+s})-f(N_s)\mid \mathcal F_t^0]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-\lambda t}}{k!}(f(N_t+k)-f(N_t))$ and also how we can deduce $Af(x)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\mathbb E^x(f(N_t))-f(x)}{t}=\lambda(f(x+1)-f(x))$ where $N_0=x$. Thank you.